# A general explanation of rim, tire and tube specifications

Tags: tire, wheels

My bike's manufacturer page specifies that it has a rim size of `700CX14GX36H`.  It provides a tire size of `7X28C`.  It also mentions that it uses high performance `700C` tires, which I think is also referenced in the rim size.

I just replaced my tube by myself for the first time, and it was easy enough to determine that I needed a 700x28c size tube, but I would really like to know what all these specifications I'm seeing mean.

**Can someone provide an explanation of what general rim, tire and tube size specifications mean?**

Comment: I'm not sure that a "general" explanation is possible. As a comment in a related question states, "manufacturers kind of made it up as they went along":  http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured#comment14888_9238

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`700CX14GX36H` means it's a:

- 700c rim (actually ISO 622mm diameter, as the [Sheldon Brown](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html) page linked by Brad describes)
- taking 14 gauge spokes
- with 36 spoke holes

So, you need to know the `700c` bit if you're buying tyres or tubes, you need to know the `14g` bit if you're replacing spokes, and you need to know the `36H` bit if you're re-lacing the rim to a new hub (which will need to have 36 spoke holes to match).

### Some Context

700c and 14 gauge spokes is standard for road bike wheels.
36 is a fairly high spoke count, meaning it should be durable and relatively easy to repair and re-true. On the other hand, lower spoke-count wheels may be lighter and more aerodynamic (at the possible cost of being more fragile and harder to repair).

---

> Can someone provide an explanation of what general tire and tube size specifications mean?

`700x23` means a tyre fitting a 700c rim, with approximate inflated cross-sectional diameter of 23mm. `700x32` is a fatter (32mm vs. 23mm) tyre for the same diameter rim. Note that even for the "correct" diameter, different tyres fit more or less easily on different rims.

A tube described as `700x18-23` would fit the first (`700x23`) tyre, but would be likely to burst before filling the greater volume of the fatter `700x32` tyre.

As for a *general* explanation ... Sheldon's table is probably the best you're going to get.

Comment: It should be noted that that nomenclature is *just* the rim nomenclature, and it oddly doesn't (per the above description) define the rim width.  A tire will come with an entirely different string of incomprehensible numbers.