# How to measure the size of a suitable tire for my bike?

Tags: tire

If I have the diameter of the rim of my bike and also have the width o this rim, how can I determine which tire is good for me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are tire sizes measured?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured)

Comment: If there's a tire on the rim, read the numbers off of it.

Answer (score 1):

Measure the diameter of the bead seat (i.e. the place where the tire bead will sit).  It will most likely be one of these:

- 559mm = MTB 26 inch tire.
- 622mm = 700C (a.k.a 29er)
- 630mm = 27 inch that is old enough to remember the Bee Gees.

If it's not one of those, look it up here:  http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#iso

The new tire will have a marking on it like **28-622**.  That second number is the diameter.

Comment: Also 650b (584 mm) is making a comeback.

Comment: 28-622 the first number is the width in mm!

Comment: But note that the tire width is greater than the rim width.