# Choosing new tires: can't find my size on schwalbe site

Tags: tire

My bicycle is Merida Crossway MD-40. I Measured the tires and got the following numbers: 701mm x 41mm. Or 27,42 In x 1,6 In.

I wanted to buy one of [Schwalbe tires](http://www.schwalbe.com/en/road.html) for it. But to my surprise my size was missing on their site.

Is my size somewhat non-standard? Why doesn't Schwalbe produce this size? Are there other companies that do? I wanted to buy slicks with puncture protection.

Comment: You're measuring the tires incorrectly (which is to say you're measuring them).  Look on the side of an existing tire.  You will see the 700c designation and an ISO designation.  Your new tire needs to match the ISO designation -- something like 40-622.  You can, within limits, change the width (the "40" value), but the rim diameter (the "622" value) must match exactly.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Yes, I measured the outer diameter, and not the inner. Which must be 622. But the width of the tire is definitely 41 mm.

Comment: **DON'T MEASURE!**  Look on the side of the tire.  Width is "nominal", and in reality varies based on rim width, tread thickness, and the whims of the tire manufacturer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your bike had these tyres as stock in 2015 *Cross 40c Front - Cross 40c Rear* according to http://www.tredz.co.uk/.Merida-Crossway-40-2015-Hybrid-Sports-Bike_74298.htm

2014 version was listed as Tyres:  *Cross 700 40C*

So you have a 700c rim which can take a 40mm wide tyre.

Confirm this by looking at the sidewall of the tyres, it should say 622-40 or 40-622 somewhere on it.

Any cyclocross tyre should be good up to a width of 40mm, and you might be able to go a little bit larger if the frame and brakes have clearance.

TBH tyre sizing nomenclature is a horrendous mess.  If you want to know more, click here [How are tire sizes measured?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured)

Comment: It says: 42 - 622 (700 x 40c - 28 x 1 5/8)

Comment: @user4035  Which is what Criggie said. If you read his linked answer it will hopefully all make sense.

Comment: Just a quick note that it will be easier to find touring tyres in the 40-42c range than cyclocross tyres.  Whilst there is demand for larger CX tyres for the gravel grinding and adventure cross communities, tyre manufacturers havn't quite caught up yet.