# Tire size change

Tags: tire

Hi I have original mtn bike tires of 26 x 1.95 on my bike but would like to change to smaller hybrid tires can I use 26 x 1.75 or must I stay with same size. Thanks

Comment: Unless the rims you have are unusually wide, you should be able to make that change with no difficulty.

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @Lourdes. I'm flagging this question as a duplicate, since it already has been answered. Check out the answers given for the "duplicate", even if the question doesn't seem the same to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are tire sizes measured?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, 1.75 should be fine for your bike.