# What Innertube is needed for my Schwinn Men's Volare 1200 Bike, 700c, Grey

Tags: innertube

I thought I purchased the right size. Two times I have gotten this wrong. 
Can any body point me in the right direction? i was hoping to find some on Amazon. And it is so confusing...

[https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00P0IN13K/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00P0IN13K)

Comment: HAH!  That amazon page says: "Wheel Size  700 inches"    I think a 1778 cm wheel would be quite hard to ride!

Comment: As Criggie says, read the writing on the (side)wall.  If you know the tire size you know the tube size.

Answer (score 1):

Bike tyre sizing is a horrible mess.

Your wheel is a 700c - that means the diameter of the whole wheel.  you have to get a tube that is a 700.

The second number on the tube relates to the width of the tyre, and is often given as a range.   Racing tyres are 18-23 mm, the next band is often 25-35,

So you need to read the writing on the sidewall of your tyre and see if its a 700-28c or similar.

It doesn't matter what width of tyre the bike came with, what matters is the width of tyre on the bike now.

Refer to [How are tire sizes measured?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured) for more info.

Comment: Thanks. the tube reads "700 X 25/32C"                                                       and underneath it  shows" 25/32 -622/630

Comment: @AndrewBennett  Great - your tube is the "middle" size so it suits tyres with a width of 25mm to 32mm.   The 622 number means the same as the 700c number, and 630 is an older sizing also known as 27".  So that tube suits a range of sizes.    NOW we need to know what's written on the sidewall of your tyre.