# Restoring a 1954 Taylor tricycle

Tags: tire, size

I am searching to replace the front tire.
It has a Swan tire, but the size is more important. Measures 12 x 1.75
Pliable enough to remount on rim

Comment: OK but what's your question? If you're asking us to recommend a suitable tyre or supplier, that's off-topic, here, as the answer tends to go out of date quickly so is unlikely to be useful to anyone after you.

Comment: Measured inch sizes do not really correspond to nominal inch sizes. Measuring the rim in millimeters is more helpful. Check also https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured

Comment: See (you may have to look closely) if the existing tire has a metric size marking on the sidewall, something like 44-203.  The first number is the tire width, and the second number is the rim diameter.  Any tire with the identical rim diameter and roughly the same width should work.  But if this marking is absent you have to measure the rim and hope for the best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing a 1950s or early 1960 solid rubber 20" bicycle tire](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/43780/replacing-a-1950s-or-early-1960-solid-rubber-20-bicycle-tire)

Comment: @DanielRHicks I'd bet the tyre is old enough to predate metric measurements on the side.

Comment: @Criggie - If it's the original.  If it was replaced once 25 years ago it qualifies as "new".

Comment: @DianeCarsia  I think your best option is to take the front rim/wheel into a Local Bike Shop and try a few smaller sizes.  Avoid the bike shops that only do racing bikes, try and find a smaller shop that is packed full.