# Which rim tape size fits my bike?

Tags: wheels, rim-tape

I need to replace the rim tape of my back wheel as it's pretty damaged and it's popping my wheels all the time. Finally made sense of the cause and I'm in need of a replacement. However, I'm unsure of the size that I need.

My wheel size is: **37-622 (28 x 1 5/8 x 1 3/8 - 700 x 35C) HS297**

Now I also measured the width of the rim tape manually and it's roughly 2cm.

These are some of the amazon results of rim tapes, but I'm not sure which one fits my bike:

https://www.amazon.de/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?__mk_de_DE=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=rim+tape

Your help would be highly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

Pictures of my rim: [Rim 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr4le.jpg), [Rim 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRJht.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How are tire sizes measured?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured)

Comment: The shape of the inside of rims varies quite a bit. Without a good photo showing your current rim strip and how it fits into the rim, I can't give a very good recommendation. Rim strips are typically measured in mm width, so a 20mm strip should match what you have. 20-622 would be the ISO number.

Comment: Duct tape, ripped to width.  Or, to be a little more elegant, "hockey tape".

Comment: Note that the Amazon link shows "rim strips" (not "tape"), which are "rubber" strips cut to length and fused in a loop so that they stretch over the rim and stay in place (if they do) just based on tension (no adhesive involved).  Bike shops like these because they're quick and easy to deal with, if you have the exactly right one, but they don't really allow for "field modification".

Comment: Get a ruler and measure the old rim strip/tape's width. Given that a velox rim tape is about 2 dollars and will last a long time, no need to do some duct tape or hockey tape or electrical tape nonsense. Velox sells a 10 mm width, 16 mm width, 19 mm width, 22 mm width; since you measured ~ 2 cm, measure more carefully.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses. I added 2 pictures of my rim if that helps.

Comment: With that style of rim you need to make sure that the strip/tape is wide enough to completely cover the round holes you see in the rim.  With other styles you only need to cover the spoke ends, but with your rims the tube will puncture if forced through the holes, even if contact with the spoke ends does not occur.

Answer (score 3):

I’m pretty sure the wheel size you quoted is what’s written on your tires i.e. ISO 622 rim (aka 28”, 700c) with a 37mm wide tire.

You need the *internal width* between the flanges of your rims to know what size rim tape to get. This is easy to measure with the tire and tube removed.

I.e. 22-622 rim tape is for ISO 622 diameter rims with 22mm internal width.

Comment: Actually, width is not that easy to measure, even with the tire off.  And note that length doesn't much matter, so long as the tape is long enough -- you can always cut it shorter.  (Rim *strips* are another matter.)

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks Can one not just use a ruler to measure between the rim flanges?

Comment: You can approximate it with a ruler, but, especially with "deep" rims, it's hard to guess what width tape will fit without either not completely covering the essentials or slopping off to one side.  To make a crude analogy, it's like trying to fit a bikini without trying it on.

Comment: Gotcha, there's a difference between the width at the tire bead and in the 'valley' where the tape sits. Having some calipers - even cheap ones - would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I might go with the size you suggest + 20-622 just to be safe. I added 2 pictures of my rim if that helps with anything - maybe it can help with a more specific size suggestion.