# Is this the correct Bike tire?

Tags: tire

This is the number inside if my current bike tire

> 32-622(700x32c-28x1 5/3x1 1/4

I found two Amazon tires are these correct?

Tire 1 : [https://www.amazon.com/Zol-Velocita-Bicycle-700x32C-G5013/dp/B07DJY83WR/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07DJY83WR)

Tire 2: [https://www.amazon.com/Kenda-Kwest-700x32C-Clincher-K-Shield/dp/B00699MERI/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00699MERI)

Also is this how I should be searching for bike tires, just using 700x32c

Comment: Please don't obfuscate links by using an url shortener. Paste the direct links instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How are tire sizes measured?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/9238/how-are-tire-sizes-measured)

Answer (score 2):

Yes - your specific tyre is a "32-622" according to its ETRTO measurements.

Thats a 622mm bead seat diameter, and a width of 32mm.  The other numbers are all older obsoleted systems of measurement that mean about the same thing.